# Bootstrap-3-Typeahead: not working "Bloodhound" (suggestion engine)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I am new in JavaScript\Bootstrap and trying to use the "Bootstrap-3-Typeahead" (https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead). Does anyone have any working example of using "Bloodhound" (suggestion engine) ? Examples from the web refer to older versions of Typeahead. Why doesn't work the following code ?:

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
      var numbers = new Bloodhound({
      datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
      queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
      local:  ["Test1","Test2","Test3","aTest4","aTest5","aTest6"]
     });
     numbers.initialize();
     $(".typeahead").typeahead(
      {items: 4},
      {source:numbers}); 
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

The github repository you refer in the opening question is based off the older version of Twitter-typeahead which has **NOT** received any updates since 3+ years now(checkout [github](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/commits/master)). But there's an actively maintained [fork](https://github.com/corejavascript/typeahead.js). (as of 2018)

There is a step-by-step **[Typeahead Tutorial @Digital Fortress](http://digitalfortress.tech/tutorial/smart-search-using-twitter-typeahead-bloodhound/)** with **JS Fiddles** to get you started with typeahead and Bloodhound.